# Scanning specific branches with TruffleHog in remote repositories

Tags: git, github

So I am aware that you can specify a branch with TruffleHog when scanning git repositories after you've cloned them locally through the following:

`trufflehog git --branch [branch-name] [your-repo-url]`

However, say I'm working with GitHub Enterprise and trying to scan repositories remotely, without cloning every single one on the filesystem (for a bit more context, this is as part of a loop that goes through thousands of repos and performs this security scan).

I have already tried to something along the lines of the following commands:

- `trufflehog git --json --token [PAT] --endpoint [GHE_URL] --repo [GHE_URL/REPO] --branch master`
- `trufflehog github --json --token [PAT] --endpoint [GHE_URL] --repo [GHE_URL/REPO] --branch master`

in the hope it *might just* work despite knowing `--branch` isn't present in the help/man page for the `github` specifier, while `git` doesn't support `--token`.

Is there an actual way of doing this for just a specific branch (maybe a term/regex I might give it for name matching)? Perhaps a way to specify the branch name within the repository name in the `--repo` option?

To me this seems somewhat of a pretty basic functionality so it might just be me who's missing something. Thanks in advance!